# Why do some people put methods in the .h file and in the interface piece of code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Recently I have been wondering why people sometimes put methods in the .h and interface areas of the code. I'm just asking because I know that it is not exactly necessary.

For example:

```
.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction) methodOne:(id)sender;
- (BOOL) doesChickenTasteGood;
```

and also:

```
.m

import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction) methodOne:(id)sender;
- (BOOL) doesChickenTasteGood;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction) methodOne:(id)sender {
      NSLog(@"Yay you poked me");
}

- (BOOL) doesChickenTasteGood {
      return YES;
}

@end
```

I'm just wondering if I should be putting some of my methods these areas.

EDIT: I am not asking why someone would redeclare these methods in both the .h and the interface part of the code. I am just asking why someone would put methods outside of the implementation of the .m file.

Comment: Are you specifically asking why someone would declare a method in the interface in a header and then redeclare *exactly the same method* in a class extension?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer Im just asking why someone would declare a method anywhere other than the implementation.

Comment: ok, I would suggest not making the method declarations exactly the same in your example, since that changes the question to something a little different.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by different

Comment: Well, redeclaring exactly the same methods would be unnecessary and a mistake. OTOH, declaring different methods in the public interface versus an extension is a useful technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would declare a method in the header if you want it to be visible to other classes. Methods declared only in the implementation file are invisible to other classes at compile-time, and so are effectively *private* (they can still be called due to Objective-C's dynamic dispatch mechanism, but you'll get a warning at the least.)

Methods are placed in an `@interface` block in the implementation file as a way of declaring they exist prior to their use. This allows for more organized code (e.g. an `@interface` block that contains only graphics methods, or one that contains only math methods) while maintaining privacy from callers.

If you have no methods in your header, then calling code will have no idea what to do with instances of your class.

Comment: I'd like to mention that adding method declarations in a private category in the .m file (as shown in the original question's code) is obsolete now with the modern Objective-C compiler. That used to be necessary if your methods were called out of order from their implementation.

Comment: @rmaddy: It is and it isn't. It's still common practice for the sake of bookkeeping.

Comment: I don't follow. What bookkeeping?

Comment: @rmaddy: If the policy in place is to forward-declare all methods, it's easier to keep track of what methods are in a class and where to find them. That's the theory anyway.

Comment: Forward-declaring all methods is a needless exercise that leads to additional, unnecessary maintenance. At least with the modern compiler. Just my 2¢.

Comment: @rmaddy: I'm neither agreeing nor disagreeing. I'm just stating a still-common policy.

Answer (score 3):

The .h file constitutes the public methods of your class. If you want others to be able to call your `doesChickenTasteGood` method, it needs to be declared in the .h because that's what other classes will `#import`.